# WordAutomationService Application Powershell SP2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

Is there a powershell script that will install WordAutomationService Application?

Im using SharePoint 2013.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SharePoint 2013: How to Configure the Word Automation Service Application using PowerShell](http://njbblog.blogspot.com/2014/01/sharepoint-2013-how-to-configure-word.html)

1. Document the Naming Convention

Determine a naming convention for each of the Word Automation Service Application components.  Document the naming convention.

Example:

```
Application Pool Service Account:  Domain\SvcAccount (this should already be created) 
Application Pool: SvcApp_SPServiceApplicationPool_02 (this should already be created)
Service Application: SvcApp_SPWordConversionServiceApplication_01
Service Application Proxy:  SvcApp_SPWordConversionServiceApplication_01_Proxy_01
```

2. Open the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as Administrator.
3. Verify the Name of the Application Pool.

   Get-SPServiceApplicationPool | Select Name
4. Get the existing Application Pool.

   $SvcAppPool02 = Get-SPServiceApplicationPool "SvcApp_SPServiceApplicationPool_02"
5. Open the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell as Administrator.
6. Create the Service Application and assign it to the Application Pool.

   $SvcApp = New-SPWordConversionServiceApplication –ApplicationPool $SvcAppPool02 -Name "SvcApp_SPWordConversionServiceApplication_01" -DatabaseName "SvcApp_SPWordConversionServiceApplication_01_DB_01" -DatabaseServer "SQL Alias Name"

The Proxy is created when the New Service Application cmdlet is run.  It does not appear that the name of the Proxy may be set or changed independently for this Service Application.

7. Verify Service Application.

   Get-SPServiceApplication | Select Name
8. Verify Service Application Proxy

   Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | Select Name

Comment: Thanks Waqas - that really helped. I also noticed that if you just add -default to it it will add the default service application proxy.

Comment: that is correct, if that reply helpful then mark it answer alnog with up vote...it will help others